# Allow null to be used like a number in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am wondering if there is an option that allows null to be used like a 0 in typescripts compiler options.

I know I can cast null to a number by doing `Number(null)`, but I would prefer just being able to use variables that can be null without doing that.

A similar solution to `Number(null)` (`null??0`) (answered here: [Allow nullable operands in less- or greater-than comparisons in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59472015/allow-nullable-operands-in-less-or-greater-than-comparisons-in-typescript)) is a code work around; however, I am looking for a typescript compiler option that allows for this.

example of what I am looking to be able to do. (without getting a type error)

```js
const x = null

console.log(x>0)
console.log(x<0)
console.log(x<=0)
console.log(x>=0)
```

Javascript has no problem treating null as 0.

(turning strict mode off allows for this, but I want to be able to use strict mode and JUST have this turned off)

Comment: Why are you looking to do this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Permitting code that looks like that would be quite confusing, at least to me...

Comment: The database I am using has a lot of null/number values used for linking together tables (its a sql database) and I would like the types to be correct, however while converting over to typescript there are a lot of tableId > 0 and tableId > 1 type if statements to see if they have extra information in another table that can be loaded. And because of latter I cant just do a nullish comparison.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow nullable operands in less- or greater-than comparisons in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59472015/allow-nullable-operands-in-less-or-greater-than-comparisons-in-typescript)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I don't think it is any more confusing than `if (Number(tableId) > 1)`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I am more looking for a typescript setting that I can turn off, not a code workaround.

Comment: What is the result you expect from every evaluation? is null bigger, smaller or equal to zero?

Comment: You can turn off `strictNullChecks`, but that has a broader impact than just this number comparison case.

Comment: @HuLuViCa null is defined to be shallowly equal to zero in javascript

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Yeah, strict: false lets me do the number comparisons and still have strictNullChecks partially working (like warnings on undefined arrays), which made me think it was a more modular option than that.

Comment: I didn't mean turning off `strict` mode entirely, just `strictNullChecks`.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I know, I was implying that that broader impact you mentioned was a little bit too much because of the potential undefined problems. Sorry I can see how what I said was confusing.

Comment: There is a linked answer in one of the previous comments. and that has a mention of [Non-Null Assertion Operator (!)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-). What do you think about using it? With that, you should be able to do `console.log(x! > 0);`... However, I'm sure you already would have noticed  `js` behavior with `null` and `relational operators`, `x! > 0` and `x! < 0`, both returns `false`, which could have catastrophic implications on the correctness of your programs.

Answer (score 1):

You could set `strictNullChecks` into your `tsconfig.json`, but you have to annotate the type

```js
const x: number = null
```

But please, pay attention, `x` is and will be null for JS.

Comment: username checks out